# Don't allow to TextView fill the entire Column

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

I'm developing an Android app.

I have this layout:

[image]

I don't want to let a textview fill a entire column. As you can see on previous image there is a TextView surrounded with a blue rectangle (in fact is selected). This is the XML code that creates that TableRow:

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFactLoc"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/layout_fac_location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/factLocVal"
        android:layout_span="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/textview_background"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtConFactLoc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/layout_confirm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rGroupFactLoc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rFactLocYes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/layout_yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rFactLocNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_no" />

    </RadioGroup>

</TableRow>
```

Is inside a TableLayout with eight columns. This is the beginning for TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPONo"
            android:layout_weight=".125"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_po_no"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pONoVal"
            android:layout_weight=".125"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/textview_background"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtIndNo"
            android:layout_weight=".125"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_ind_no"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/indNoVal"
            android:layout_weight=".125"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/textview_background"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeIn"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_time_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeInVal"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/textview_background"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeOut"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_time_out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeOutVal"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/textview_background"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>
```

Some textViews have a background color. As you can see all of them fill its columns and I don't want that because this form looks very ugly.

How can I change TextView width? If I have set android:layout_span="2" I can't change its width.

Answer (score 0):

With android:stretchColumns, you can decide which columns are allowed to be streched (put it in the TableLayout tag).

```
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand your answer. I have put `android:stretchColumns="*"` in my TableLayout tag.